# Youtube API Client in Android App Question

Tags: android

I am using a webview to display youtube video in my app. I dont have an API key or anything else to play the video. I am just using a webview with the youtube <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/... I want to upload the App to Google Play. I understand I need to have a Terms of Service and Privacy Policy, do I also need to get an API Key from youtube if I am only using the frame in the webview to comply with all legal requierments? Any help is appreciated! thanks.

Look many documents and info not sure what is the right way of uploading an app to Google Play that uses the Youtube API Client.

Comment: Voting to close as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You need to review YouTube's terms and / or consult a lawyer.